# How to get MacOsX Logged-in User's user id in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Please let me know how to get the currently logged-in user's user id in Objective-C.  I would like to get the user id of the logged-in user that's currently using the computer locally.  My command-line program is running as root and I want to find the currently logged-in user's user id.  Thanks.

Comment: There may be more than one user logged in, including -- via fast user switching and/or screen sharing -- more than one user using the GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser() might work for you. It will return uid and gid of the current console user.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStoreCopySpecific/Reference/reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2001/qa1133.html

Comment: This link provides sample code: http://superuser.com/questions/180819/how-can-you-find-out-the-currently-logged-in-user-in-the-os-x-gui

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NSUserName()`. This will return the name of the current logged in user.

```
NSString *userName = NSUserName();
```

Additionally, there is also an `NSFullUserName()` function.

```
NSFullUserName() // "John Doe"
NSUserName()     // "jdoe"
```

Comment: Thanks, MJN.  I'm actually looking for a number (uid) like when you execute the 'id' command in a Terminal window.

Comment: I don't believe that'll work for a process running as root, though.

Comment: `unsigned int myuid = getuid();`

Comment: I think that won't work for the OP, because his process is "running as root" - possibly launched as system daemon or agent - outside any user context. The Appkit functions you suggest will work in the context of an App running for some logged in user, not a UI-less process running as root.

Answer (score 3):

On macOS, multiple users can be logged in at once. Use `utmpx` functions to iterate over user sessions.

### SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser

To discover the user with the active graphical session, use the [`SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration/1517123-scdynamicstorecopyconsoleuser) function in the `SystemConfiguration.framework`.

Note that Apple's [QA1133](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1133/_index.html) mentions this function may be deprecated in the future:

> **Warning:** The System Configuration framework mechanism for determining the current console user has a number of important caveats:
>
> - It assumes that the computer has a single GUI console. While that's true currently, it may not be true forever. If you use this technique you will have to change your code if this situation changes.
> - It has no way of indicating that multiple users are logged in.
> - It has no way of indicating that a user is logged in but has switched to the login window.
>
> Because of these issues, routines like SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser exist only for compatibility purposes. It's likely that they will be formally deprecated in a future version of Mac OS X.

### Owner of `/dev/console`

An alternative approach is to `fstat` the path `/dev/console`:

```
struct stat info;
if (lstat(_PATH_CONSOLE,&info) == 0) {
    printf("%s is owned by %d\n",_PATH_CONSOLE,info.st_uid);
}
```

Comment: Excuse me... what's wrong with simple posix getuid() call? will it not provide the correct user Id? where do these methods deviate?

Comment: These methods obtain the user **with the active graphical session** and not the owner of the calling process.